# How to parse Json that contain uneven items inside a dictionary

Tags: json, swift3

I wanted to test parsing json file.
I have the following Json file which store as internal file in the project.

The problem :

- the room has uneven items ; some have 2 item, some have 3 items.

How to handle this case?

```
-------------- Json file:

[  
   {  
      "_id":"598f1442bf068c0b28c2f991",
      "purpose":"Meeting with Jay",
      "date":"2017-08-09T03:32:43.395Z",
      "__v":0,
      "room":{  
         "capacity":0,
         "address":"-"
      }
   },
   {  
      "_id":"598f147ebf068c0b28c2f992",
      "purpose":"Presentation to mike",
      "date":"2017-08-10T07:45:43.395Z",
      "__v":0,
      "room":{  
         "name":"SC-07-01",
         "capacity":10,
         "address":"The Hi Five"
      }
   },
   {  
      "_id":"598f1508bf068c0b28c2f993",
      "purpose":"Demo to users",
      "date":"2017-08-11T09:00:00.000Z",
      "__v":0,
      "room":{  
         "name":"SC-08-01",
         "capacity":30,
         "address":"The Hi Five"
      }
   },
   {  
      "_id":"598f16b3bf068c0b28c2f994",
      "purpose":"Cooking with William",
      "date":"2017-08-09T05:26:43.395Z",
      "__v":0,
      "room":{  
         "name":"MBC-#07-01",
         "capacity":10,
         "address":"Maple Tree garden"
      }
   }
]
```

**-- Update --**

```
class RoomBooking {

  var purpose:String?
  var date:String?  // need to take the date and hh:mm out from it
  var hhmm: String?
  var bookDate: String? 
  Var room:Room?

   init(purpose:String, date:String,hhmm :String, bookDate:String, room : Room) {

    self.purpose = purpose
    self.date = date
    self.hhmm = hhmm
    self.bookDate = bookDate
    self.room = room

    }
}

class Room {
    var name:String?
    var capacity:Int?
    var address:String?
}


//-1- How to iterate the room?
//-2- How to get the date and time (hh:mm) from the date Object

//-3- create an array object of RoomBooking 


var rmbookingArray = [RoomBooking]() 

for user in array {

      if let userDict = user as? [String:Any]{

            if let purpose = userDict.value(forKey: "purpose") {
                                    return purpose as! String
                                }
                                return "No purpose enter"

                            }()

            if let userDate = userDict.value(forKey: "date") {

                                    return date as! String
                                }
                                return "No date enter"

                            }()

            if let userRoom = ??

            }

            var roomObject = Room()
            roomObject.name = userRoom["name"] as? String
            roomObject.capacity = userRoom["capacity"] as? Int
            roomObject.address = userRoom["address"] as? String

        var rb = RoomBooking()
        rb.purpose = userPurpose
        rb.date = userDate
        rb.room = roomObject

        rmbookingArray.append(rb)

     }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: By default you should have your rooms to have 3 items, if an item doesn't have a item just make it `null`. This should improve your parsing issue

Comment: Can you should me how to do it. I am quite new to swift and json. Room should have 3, how to know when it contains 2?

Comment: for example you see how in your first object that you  have `"address": "-"`, I am guessing that was a way of saying that you don't have an address for this person. when you are parsing, you could say if `-` don't display any thing for this user's address

Comment: There are too many question marks (optionals). **Never ever declare properties as optional which are initialized in an `init` method with non-optional values**. The properties work – even better – without question marks, too.

Comment: please help.  You mean I shld use , for example, 1) var name:String! or 2)  just var name:String.  Is this correct?

Comment: **2)** No exclamation mark, no question mark. And if the value is supposed to change never consider to use constants (`let`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a class whose fields are optionals and if one of the properties in your JSON is missing, just leave the value nil. Don't use `guard` statements if you are expecting some missing fields, since `guard` always exits scope in the `else` clause. Use `if let` instead.

```
class RoomBooking {

  var purpose:String
  var date:Date
  var hhmm: String
  var bookDate: Date 
  var room:Room

   init(purpose:String, date:Date,hhmm :String, bookDate:Date, room : Room) {

    self.purpose = purpose
    self.date = date
    self.hhmm = hhmm
    self.bookDate = bookDate
    self.room = room

    }
}
class Room {
    var name:String?
    var capacity:Int?
    var address:String?
}

var rmbookingArray = [RoomBooking]()

for user in array {    
    if let userDict = user as? [String:Any]{
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.z"

        guard let userDateString = userDict["date"] as? String, let userDate = df.date(from: userDateString) else { return}
        guard let userPurpose = userDict["purpose"] as? String else { return}   
        //-- the room contain dictionary

        guard let userRoom = userDict["room"] as? [String:Any] else { return}

        var roomObject = Room()
        roomObject.name = userRoom["name"] as? String
        roomObject.capacity = userRoom["capacity"] as? Int
        roomObject.address = userRoom["address"] as? String

        let bookingDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        bookingDateFormatter.dateFormat = "hhmm"

        //I cannot see anything related to bookDate in your JSON, so bookDate is just a dummy variable, set it up to whatever you want to
        var booking = RoomBooking(purpose: userPurpose, date: userDate, hhmm: bookingDateFormatter.string(from: bookDate), bookDate: bookDate, room: roomObject)
        rmbookingArray.append(booking)
    }
}
```

If you parse your file this way, you will be able to parse each "room" element of the file even if some of the properties are missing, they will just be `nil` in the `Room` object. I left some guard statements in the code, since it seems from the example that those fields always exist. If those might be missing as well, just change them to `if let`s.

Comment: give me some time, I will come back here. your solution should be working. I am working on it now.

Comment: The json has a date like :"date":"2017-08-09T03:32:43.395Z",  How to convert the string date into Date and take the date out like yyyy mm dd and hour min like hh:mm. What I need to add to the class like var hhmm : string?

Comment: @MilkBottle updated my answer with parsing the date string into a `Date` object. For converting it back to another string representation, just use a `DateFormatter` with another dateformat.

Comment: Your advice is important. So, I dont want to use guard. I have difficulty in handling the room item. I have create 2 classes as above , the roomBooking class has hhmm and bookDate as string which get from the Date which converted from the json. need your help 1) how to iterate the room item, 2)get the HHMM, BookDate 3) is rmbookingArray append is correct?

Comment: can you help me out on this?

Comment: What do you mean, how to iterate the room item? I've already shown you how to create them. I don't know where is `BookDate` coming from, I cannot see anything related in your JSON, but I've included converting a `Date` object to _hhmm_ String representation. 3)Yes, the appending is correct. Check my updated answer. I have included the `RoomBooking` class definition as well that you should use. You should use the JSON parsing I have shown in my answer (you can change the guards to if lets if you want to), but don't use `dictionary.value(forKey:)` in `Swift`.

Comment: I m close to the solution. BUT if you notice the room is uneven which means it contains 2 items or 3 items. how to use if let for this : guard let userRoom = userDict["room"] as? [String:Any] else { return} , this guard will exit the func. I hope you dont mind showing me using If Let for this entire code.  If there is nil in the Json, I need to add some standard dummy value to it.  example: userRoom["address"]  is nil, I need to add dummy value to address. Thanks

Comment: That guard was left there intentionally. If that guard fails, it means that is no room data present at all, so there is nothing to parse, it is okay to return. Only the data __inside__ the room dictionary is uneven, which is already parsed conditionally and without returning if no data was found, so the current implementation will work just fine.